# Is it possible to check an array of strings, if an element within it could be turned into an int or double?

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, double

I was wondering if you could check the  elements in an array of strings, to see if they could be parsed into an int or double? I know you could try to parse the element and handle the exception thrown but is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a regex like this `-?\d+(.\d+)?`

```
-?     --> optional negative symbol
\d+    --> indicates a sequence of one or more numbers
.?     --> optional decimal (for floats)
(\d+)? --> optional digits following the decimal
```

the command to match would be like `str.matches("-?\\d+(.\\d+)?");` and I'd just iterate through it with an enhanced for loop. `String.matches()` is a built in `boolean` function so if the string can't be converted to a float or int then it'll return `false`.

the double `\\` is just to escape a literal `\` character.

If you don't want the pattern to match something like a portion of `fewkjnf12.345r52v` then simply just add a carat to indicate that the beginning of the float/int should have no strings, and a dollar sign to the end of the string to ensure nothing comes after it

i.e `^-?\d+(.\d+)?$`

[please visit this site to see the regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/Y0fBlH/1)

Comment: Thank you, this is probably the best approach, I appreciate your answer.